# How do I timestamp base on an index formula cell with onEdit script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make column 8 display timestamp when column 7 value changes. However, my column 7 is an index formula `=INDEX(Sheet02!C:C, MATCH(A2, Sheet02!A:A, 0))` so even though the value displayed will change, but technically there is no "onEdit" action being triggered in column 7. Does anyone know how I can change my script below to accommodate for this?

Here is the working script I have for another situation where time stamp happens on column 5 when column 4 is manually changed.

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Sheet01") { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 7 ) { //checks the column
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
var time = new Date();
time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MMM/dd/yy");
nextCell.setValue(time);
};
};
}`
```

Comment: If the change can only happen due to a user edit, even if the edit is not to the cells in question, then you just have to store the values and recheck them all on every edit to a region that might change the formula result. If the current value then doesn't equal the stored value, you write a timestamp

Comment: Another option could be to have your `onEdit` "listen" to the sheet where the edit is taking place, log the location, then transfer that to the indexed sheet and add your timestamp.